# Unable to register MBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, jmx

I am writing integration tests for a spring-boot application, and I am using a base test class for common methods and all the other common stuff. Something like this:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = ...)
@Sql(scripts = { "script1.sql", ... }, ...)
public abstract class ITBase {
...
```

I have a file generator, which is autowired into a service, which is autowired into a controller.
I am testing the controller using RestTemplate.
I would like to mock the file generator, to return just a random string.

Because it is a spring Bean, I understood I should use @MockBean annotation in my test in this way:

```
public class ControllerIT extends ITBase {

@MockBean
private FileGenerator fileGenerator;

@Test
@Transactional
public void testSomeTest() {
...
```

**My problem is:**

If I run the given test class, all tests pass. However, if I run all the test classes, I get an *UnableToRegisterMBeanException*.
The stacktrace looks like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.java:49)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManager@607624b7] with key 'environmentManager'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.gd.configurationrepository:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:796)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:111)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 31 more
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.gd.configurationrepository:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:678)
at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
... 43 more
```

*I have no hikari or whatsoever. Just a simple file generator, service and controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your root cause is that you are trying to reinstantiate an MBean.  Make sure you instantiate it once for the entire set of tests instead of once per test (probably move @MockBean to ITBase and delete from all subclasses).  The error message is

```
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.gd.configurationrepository:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
```

Answer (score 7):

I needed to switch off jmx autoconfiguration of spring boot:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    JmxAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

It is [not adviced](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-1216) to have it running with tests.

Comment: Does this disable JMX?

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the JMX (Hawtio) on teste, the best found aproach was

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.jmx.testing.enabled", havingValue = "true")
public class ObjectJMX {
```